# Selenium параметры ChromeDrive

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium

из Selenium нужно в автоматизированном режиме сохранить файл на диск по ссылке (c#)

В интернете рекомендуют для этого воспользоваться браузером, отключить диалог запроса места сохранения и задать директорию сохранения по умолчанию.

Для этого для chrome я применил такие опции:

```
OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions co = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeOptions();
co.AddArgument(@"user-data-dir=c:\Users\Gayrat\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\");
co.AddArgument(@"download.default_directory=E:\temp\5\");
co.AddArgument(@"download.prompt_for_download=false");

Browser = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver(co);
```

К сожалению сработала только одна опция - задание параметров пользователя.
Остальные пришлось задать вручную в chrome.

Подскажите пожалуйста как в Selenium для драйвера Chrome задать директорию сохранения по умолчанию и как отключить всплывающий диалог запроса сохранения?

Comment: Настройте руками через интерфейс Chrome эти параметры для вашего пользователя и не заморачивайтесь

Comment: На самом деле мне нужно менять директорию от файла к файлу

Answer (score 0):

Выяснилось что надо использовать AddUserProfilePreference

```
 var downloadDirectory = @"E:\temp\5";

            co.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", downloadDirectory);
            co.AddUserProfilePreference("download.prompt_for_download", false);
            co.AddUserProfilePreference("disable-popup-blocking", "true");

            Browser = new OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver(co);
```